# SAPUI5 get calendars child elements and add style class

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to access the single day elements of a calender element. The IDs of those elements are generated. I tried `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` as well as `this.getView().byId()` but both options didn't work. Only the calendar element has some static ID.

By using `jQuery.sap.byId("__component0---calendar--calendar1--Month0-20181212")[0]` I get some result but I am not able to add a style class:

> jQuery.sap.byId(...)[0].addStyleClass is not a function

[image]

Is there some way to add the style class?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your element from the DOM with jQuery:

```
$("__component0---calendar--calendar1--Month0-20181212")[0]
```

You can change and remove classes by using the jQuery methods [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Comment: Hi Andre. For me this does not work. The element is undefined in this case. If I do it without [0], there is only the context and addClass does not bring any result. What's the difference between "$" and "jQuery.sap.byId"?

Comment: This code is working fine for me, just make sure you use it after rendering the view. `$` sign is just a valid javascript identifier which is used as an alias for jQuery, you will need to use the `[0]` to get the HTML DOM object, if you don't use it then it will retrieve a jQuery object instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution:

```
jQuery.sap.byId("__component0---calendar--calendar1--Month0-20181212").addClass("dateBackgroundChHa");
```

Let me know if there is some better way!